# Forcing `pthread_create` to fail for test purposes

Tags: c, testing, unix, pthreads, posix

In order to test error recovery, I want to make `pthread_create` fail in a predictable manner.  The most obvious way to do that is to put a hard upper limit on the number of threads that are allowed to exist in a specific process.

On Linux, specifically, `setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC)` affects both process and thread creation; setting the limit to 1 will cause `pthread_create` to fail for any code after the `setrlimit` call.  Solaris-derived Unixes [I only tested OmniOS r151030] don't have RLIMIT_NPROC but do have a way to put a limit on the number of threads in a process via the fancier [`setrctl`](https://man.omnios.org/man2/setrctl) interface.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this from C on any other Unix I've tried.  In particular, the test program at the bottom of this question will print "fail: pthread_create succeeded" on all of (AIX 7.1, FreeBSD 12.1, NetBSD 9.3, OpenBSD 6.8).

So, the question: Please modify the test program to make the `pthread_create` call fail on one or more Unixes which are neither Linux nor Solaris.  Answers which work on a *wide variety* of Unixes are preferred (e.g. if you can exhibit one way to do this on *all* BSD-derived systems, that'd be wonderful).

Note: answers that would have side effects on processes other than the one actually executing the test program (e.g. imposing a limit on the total number of threads running under a specific uid, or the entire system) are no good to me.

---

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

static void *threadproc(void *arg)
{
    puts("fail: pthread_create succeeded");
    return arg;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct rlimit r = { 1, 1 };
    if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &r)) {
        perror("error: setrlimit failed");
        return 1;
    }
    pthread_t t;
    int err = pthread_create(&t, 0, threadproc, 0);
    if (err) {
        printf("ok: pthread_create failed (%s)\n", strerror(err));
        return 0;
    }
    err = pthread_join(t, 0);
    if (err)
        printf("error: pthread_join failed (%s)\n", strerror(err));
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Would a solution wrapping `pthread_create` work?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, this is testing an already-compiled binary (in the real test driver, there's an exec() after the setrlimit() or whatever) that might have been statically linked (so LD_PRELOAD is not an option either).

Comment: Ok. And, you can't run just this process in isolation (docker etc.)?

Comment: This is just one of many tests, and the test harness doesn't currently have the ability to do that, so, not without a great deal of extra work.

Answer (score 1):

**AIX**

[AIX `setrlimit()` has `RLIMIT_THREADS`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=g-getrlimit-getrlimit64-setrlimit-setrlimit64-vlimit-subroutine):

> RLIMIT_THREADS
>
> The maximum number of threads each process can create. This limit is enforced by the kernel and the pthread debug library.

Simply replace

```
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &r)
```

with

```
setrlimit(RLIMIT_THREADS, &r)
```

(I don't have access to an AIX instance to test, however)

**BSD**

BSD does not seem to have any equivalent that doesn't rely on per-user or whole-system limits.

Answer (score 0):

You could protect stack memory with POSIX function `int mprotect(void *addr, size_t len, int prot);`

Something like this:

```
   pthread_attr_t attr;
    // attr initialization here:
   int rc; 
   void  *mystack;
   size_t mystacksize = 2 * PTHREAD_STACK_MIN;
                                                                                
   if ( pthread_attr_init(&attr) ) {                                        
      perror("pthread_attr_init()");                                     
      return -1;
   }                                                                            
                                                                                
   // Get a big enough stack and align it on 4K boundary.
   mystack = malloc(PTHREAD_STACK_MIN * 3);
   if (!mystack) {
      perror("Unable to acquire storage.");
      return -1;
   }
   // Align stack, memory leak is possible
   mystack =  (((intptr_t)mystack) & 0xfff)
               ? (void*)( ( ((intptr_t)mystack) & ~0xfff) + 0x1000)
              : mystack;
                                                                                
    rc = pthread_attr_setstack(&attr, mystack, mystacksize);
    if (rc != 0) {                                           
        perror("pthread_attr_setstack()");
        return -1;
    } 

    // Protect stack memory:
    rc = memprotect(stack, mystacksize, PROT_NONE);
    if (rc) {
        perror("mprotect()");
        return -1;
    }

    pthread_t t;
    // Should fail, cause stack memory is protected
    int err = pthread_create(&t, attr, threadproc, 0);
    if (err) {
        printf("ok: pthread_create failed (%s)\n", strerror(err));
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's not relevant to your otherwise thoughtful answer, [but `pthread_attr_init()` isn't guaranteed to return a negative value on failure](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/pthread_attr_init.html): "Upon successful completion, `pthread_attr_destroy()` and `pthread_attr_init()` shall return a value of 0; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error."

Comment: Did you test this? For me it crashes the entire process.

Comment: @zwol It might work on BSD - ISTR reading that `pthread_create()` fails on BSD if the stack can't be accessed - either because the memory permissions aren't proper, or the address isn't in the address space.  Of course, the problem would then be getting your executable under test to behave per this answer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Just tried it on NetBSD and nope, segfault.

Comment: @zwol I'd think if any BSD had the additional checks, it'd be OpenBSD.  And it might just check for a valid address, not memory permissions.

Comment: Also crashes on OpenBSD and FreeBSD. On Darwin, pthread_attr_setstack returns EINVAL.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `ptrace` and trap/mangle the `clone` syscalls using `PTRACE_SYSCALL`

The following is for linux (x86_64) but BSD has similar but slightly different options.

Upon the "enter syscall" for `clone`, if we want to force a failure, one way [perhaps the easiest] is we set `orig_rax` to zero. This is the syscall number and 0 is an *invalid* syscall. The target program will get an `ENOSYS` error.

BSD [obviously] has to use slightly different options but the principle is the same.

---

Here is the trace program (`trace.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
//#include <syscall.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

FILE *xflog;
int mode;
int maxthr;
int clone_count;
int kicked;
struct user_regs_struct regs;

#define outf(_fmt...) \
    fprintf(xflog,_fmt)

#define REGSALL(_cmd) \
  _cmd(r15) \
  _cmd(r14) \
  _cmd(r13) \
  _cmd(r12) \
  _cmd(rbp) \
  _cmd(rbx) \
  _cmd(r11) \
  _cmd(r10) \
  _cmd(r9) \
  _cmd(r8) \
  _cmd(rax) \
  _cmd(rcx) \
  _cmd(rdx) \
  _cmd(rsi) \
  _cmd(rdi) \
  _cmd(orig_rax) \
  _cmd(rip) \
  _cmd(cs) \
  _cmd(eflags) \
  _cmd(rsp) \
  _cmd(ss) \
  _cmd(fs_base) \
  _cmd(gs_base) \
  _cmd(ds) \
  _cmd(es) \
  _cmd(fs) \
  _cmd(gs)

#define GETREG(_reg) \
    _getreg(#_reg,regs._reg);

#define MAXTHREADS          10

const char *svcname(int);
char svc_verbose[500] = {
    [__NR_clone] = 1,
};

void *
func(void *ptr)
{

    sleep(2);

    return (void *) 0;
}

void
showstop(pid_t pid,int status)
{

    outf("\n");
    outf("trace: pid=%d status=%8.8X",pid,status);

    do {
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            outf(" WIFSIGNALED signo=%d",WTERMSIG(status));
            break;
        }

        if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            outf(" WIFSTOPPED signo=%d",WSTOPSIG(status));
            break;
        }

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            outf(" WIFEXITED code=%d",WEXITSTATUS(status));
            break;
        }
    } while (0);

    outf("\n");
}

void
_getreg(const char *sym,unsigned long long val)
{

    outf("getreg: %s %16.16llX %llu\n",sym,val,val);
}

void
getregs(pid_t pid,int force)
{

    int err = ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS,pid,NULL,&regs);
    if (err < 0) {
        outf("getregs: fail -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    long long svcno = regs.orig_rax;
    long long retval = regs.rax;

    outf("getregs: SYSCALL %d %s",svcno,svcname(svcno));
    outf(" mode=%d/%s ret=%lld",mode,mode ? "exit" : "enter",retval);
    if (retval < 0)
        outf(" -- %s",strerror(-retval));
    outf("\n");

    int show = svc_verbose[svcno];

    if (show || force) {
        REGSALL(GETREG)
    }
}

void
setregs(pid_t pid)
{

    int err = ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS,pid,NULL,&regs);
    if (err < 0) {
        outf("setregs: fail -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    outf("setregs: mode=%d\n",mode);

    getregs(pid,1);

    kicked = 1;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    xflog = fopen("LOG","w");
    setlinebuf(xflog);

    maxthr = -1;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'L':
            maxthr = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (argc < 1) {
        outf("trace: need at least one arg\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    outf("trace: __NR_clone=%d\n",__NR_clone);

    int status;

    pid_t pidtop = fork();
    pid_t pidcur;

    if (pidtop == 0) {
        pidtop = getpid();
        outf("trace: child pidtop=%d\n",pidtop);
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME,pidtop);
        outf("trace: child execvp\n");
        execvp(argv[0],argv);
        outf("trace: execvp failure -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    outf("trace: parent pidtop=%d\n",pidtop);
    pidcur = waitpid(pidtop,&status,0);
    showstop(pidcur,status);
    getregs(pidcur,1);

    int err = ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,pidcur,NULL,NULL);
    if (err < 0) {
        outf("trace: PTRACE_SYSCALL/1 fail pidcur=%d -- %s\n",
            pidcur,strerror(errno));
        //break;
    }

    while (1) {
        pidcur = waitpid(-1,&status,0);
        if (pidcur < 0)
            break;

        showstop(pidcur,status);

        getregs(pidcur,kicked);
        kicked = 0;

        if (regs.orig_rax == __NR_clone) {
            if (mode == 0) {
                ++clone_count;

                // if we're over the limit, zap the syscall number to force
                // target to see EINVAL
                if ((maxthr >= 0) && (clone_count > maxthr)) {
                    regs.orig_rax = 0;
                    setregs(pidcur);
                }
            }
        }

        mode = ! mode;

        if (WIFSTOPPED(status) && (WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGSTOP)) {
        }

        int err = ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,pidcur,NULL,NULL);
        if (err < 0) {
            outf("trace: PTRACE_SYSCALL/2 fail pidcur=%d -- %s\n",
                pidcur,strerror(errno));
            //break;
        }
    }

    outf("trace: done\n");
    fclose(xflog);

    return 0;
}
#define NRALL(_cmd) \
    _cmd(read,0) \
    _cmd(write,1) \
    _cmd(open,2) \
    _cmd(close,3) \
    _cmd(stat,4) \
    _cmd(fstat,5) \
    _cmd(lstat,6) \
    _cmd(poll,7) \
    _cmd(lseek,8) \
    _cmd(mmap,9) \
    _cmd(mprotect,10) \
    _cmd(munmap,11) \
    _cmd(brk,12) \
    _cmd(rt_sigaction,13) \
    _cmd(rt_sigprocmask,14) \
    _cmd(rt_sigreturn,15) \
    _cmd(ioctl,16) \
    _cmd(pread64,17) \
    _cmd(pwrite64,18) \
    _cmd(readv,19) \
    _cmd(writev,20) \
    _cmd(access,21) \
    _cmd(pipe,22) \
    _cmd(select,23) \
    _cmd(sched_yield,24) \
    _cmd(mremap,25) \
    _cmd(msync,26) \
    _cmd(mincore,27) \
    _cmd(madvise,28) \
    _cmd(shmget,29) \
    _cmd(shmat,30) \
    _cmd(shmctl,31) \
    _cmd(dup,32) \
    _cmd(dup2,33) \
    _cmd(pause,34) \
    _cmd(nanosleep,35) \
    _cmd(getitimer,36) \
    _cmd(alarm,37) \
    _cmd(setitimer,38) \
    _cmd(getpid,39) \
    _cmd(sendfile,40) \
    _cmd(socket,41) \
    _cmd(connect,42) \
    _cmd(accept,43) \
    _cmd(sendto,44) \
    _cmd(recvfrom,45) \
    _cmd(sendmsg,46) \
    _cmd(recvmsg,47) \
    _cmd(shutdown,48) \
    _cmd(bind,49) \
    _cmd(listen,50) \
    _cmd(getsockname,51) \
    _cmd(getpeername,52) \
    _cmd(socketpair,53) \
    _cmd(setsockopt,54) \
    _cmd(getsockopt,55) \
    _cmd(clone,56) \
    _cmd(fork,57) \
    _cmd(vfork,58) \
    _cmd(execve,59) \
    _cmd(exit,60) \
    _cmd(wait4,61) \
    _cmd(kill,62) \
    _cmd(uname,63) \
    _cmd(semget,64) \
    _cmd(semop,65) \
    _cmd(semctl,66) \
    _cmd(shmdt,67) \
    _cmd(msgget,68) \
    _cmd(msgsnd,69) \
    _cmd(msgrcv,70) \
    _cmd(msgctl,71) \
    _cmd(fcntl,72) \
    _cmd(flock,73) \
    _cmd(fsync,74) \
    _cmd(fdatasync,75) \
    _cmd(truncate,76) \
    _cmd(ftruncate,77) \
    _cmd(getdents,78) \
    _cmd(getcwd,79) \
    _cmd(chdir,80) \
    _cmd(fchdir,81) \
    _cmd(rename,82) \
    _cmd(mkdir,83) \
    _cmd(rmdir,84) \
    _cmd(creat,85) \
    _cmd(link,86) \
    _cmd(unlink,87) \
    _cmd(symlink,88) \
    _cmd(readlink,89) \
    _cmd(chmod,90) \
    _cmd(fchmod,91) \
    _cmd(chown,92) \
    _cmd(fchown,93) \
    _cmd(lchown,94) \
    _cmd(umask,95) \
    _cmd(gettimeofday,96) \
    _cmd(getrlimit,97) \
    _cmd(getrusage,98) \
    _cmd(sysinfo,99) \
    _cmd(times,100) \
    _cmd(ptrace,101) \
    _cmd(getuid,102) \
    _cmd(syslog,103) \
    _cmd(getgid,104) \
    _cmd(setuid,105) \
    _cmd(setgid,106) \
    _cmd(geteuid,107) \
    _cmd(getegid,108) \
    _cmd(setpgid,109) \
    _cmd(getppid,110) \
    _cmd(getpgrp,111) \
    _cmd(setsid,112) \
    _cmd(setreuid,113) \
    _cmd(setregid,114) \
    _cmd(getgroups,115) \
    _cmd(setgroups,116) \
    _cmd(setresuid,117) \
    _cmd(getresuid,118) \
    _cmd(setresgid,119) \
    _cmd(getresgid,120) \
    _cmd(getpgid,121) \
    _cmd(setfsuid,122) \
    _cmd(setfsgid,123) \
    _cmd(getsid,124) \
    _cmd(capget,125) \
    _cmd(capset,126) \
    _cmd(rt_sigpending,127) \
    _cmd(rt_sigtimedwait,128) \
    _cmd(rt_sigqueueinfo,129) \
    _cmd(rt_sigsuspend,130) \
    _cmd(sigaltstack,131) \
    _cmd(utime,132) \
    _cmd(mknod,133) \
    _cmd(uselib,134) \
    _cmd(personality,135) \
    _cmd(ustat,136) \
    _cmd(statfs,137) \
    _cmd(fstatfs,138) \
    _cmd(sysfs,139) \
    _cmd(getpriority,140) \
    _cmd(setpriority,141) \
    _cmd(sched_setparam,142) \
    _cmd(sched_getparam,143) \
    _cmd(sched_setscheduler,144) \
    _cmd(sched_getscheduler,145) \
    _cmd(sched_get_priority_max,146) \
    _cmd(sched_get_priority_min,147) \
    _cmd(sched_rr_get_interval,148) \
    _cmd(mlock,149) \
    _cmd(munlock,150) \
    _cmd(mlockall,151) \
    _cmd(munlockall,152) \
    _cmd(vhangup,153) \
    _cmd(modify_ldt,154) \
    _cmd(pivot_root,155) \
    _cmd(_sysctl,156) \
    _cmd(prctl,157) \
    _cmd(arch_prctl,158) \
    _cmd(adjtimex,159) \
    _cmd(setrlimit,160) \
    _cmd(chroot,161) \
    _cmd(sync,162) \
    _cmd(acct,163) \
    _cmd(settimeofday,164) \
    _cmd(mount,165) \
    _cmd(umount2,166) \
    _cmd(swapon,167) \
    _cmd(swapoff,168) \
    _cmd(reboot,169) \
    _cmd(sethostname,170) \
    _cmd(setdomainname,171) \
    _cmd(iopl,172) \
    _cmd(ioperm,173) \
    _cmd(create_module,174) \
    _cmd(init_module,175) \
    _cmd(delete_module,176) \
    _cmd(get_kernel_syms,177) \
    _cmd(query_module,178) \
    _cmd(quotactl,179) \
    _cmd(nfsservctl,180) \
    _cmd(getpmsg,181) \
    _cmd(putpmsg,182) \
    _cmd(afs_syscall,183) \
    _cmd(tuxcall,184) \
    _cmd(security,185) \
    _cmd(gettid,186) \
    _cmd(readahead,187) \
    _cmd(setxattr,188) \
    _cmd(lsetxattr,189) \
    _cmd(fsetxattr,190) \
    _cmd(getxattr,191) \
    _cmd(lgetxattr,192) \
    _cmd(fgetxattr,193) \
    _cmd(listxattr,194) \
    _cmd(llistxattr,195) \
    _cmd(flistxattr,196) \
    _cmd(removexattr,197) \
    _cmd(lremovexattr,198) \
    _cmd(fremovexattr,199) \
    _cmd(tkill,200) \
    _cmd(time,201) \
    _cmd(futex,202) \
    _cmd(sched_setaffinity,203) \
    _cmd(sched_getaffinity,204) \
    _cmd(set_thread_area,205) \
    _cmd(io_setup,206) \
    _cmd(io_destroy,207) \
    _cmd(io_getevents,208) \
    _cmd(io_submit,209) \
    _cmd(io_cancel,210) \
    _cmd(get_thread_area,211) \
    _cmd(lookup_dcookie,212) \
    _cmd(epoll_create,213) \
    _cmd(epoll_ctl_old,214) \
    _cmd(epoll_wait_old,215) \
    _cmd(remap_file_pages,216) \
    _cmd(getdents64,217) \
    _cmd(set_tid_address,218) \
    _cmd(restart_syscall,219) \
    _cmd(semtimedop,220) \
    _cmd(fadvise64,221) \
    _cmd(timer_create,222) \
    _cmd(timer_settime,223) \
    _cmd(timer_gettime,224) \
    _cmd(timer_getoverrun,225) \
    _cmd(timer_delete,226) \
    _cmd(clock_settime,227) \
    _cmd(clock_gettime,228) \
    _cmd(clock_getres,229) \
    _cmd(clock_nanosleep,230) \
    _cmd(exit_group,231) \
    _cmd(epoll_wait,232) \
    _cmd(epoll_ctl,233) \
    _cmd(tgkill,234) \
    _cmd(utimes,235) \
    _cmd(vserver,236) \
    _cmd(mbind,237) \
    _cmd(set_mempolicy,238) \
    _cmd(get_mempolicy,239) \
    _cmd(mq_open,240) \
    _cmd(mq_unlink,241) \
    _cmd(mq_timedsend,242) \
    _cmd(mq_timedreceive,243) \
    _cmd(mq_notify,244) \
    _cmd(mq_getsetattr,245) \
    _cmd(kexec_load,246) \
    _cmd(waitid,247) \
    _cmd(add_key,248) \
    _cmd(request_key,249) \
    _cmd(keyctl,250) \
    _cmd(ioprio_set,251) \
    _cmd(ioprio_get,252) \
    _cmd(inotify_init,253) \
    _cmd(inotify_add_watch,254) \
    _cmd(inotify_rm_watch,255) \
    _cmd(migrate_pages,256) \
    _cmd(openat,257) \
    _cmd(mkdirat,258) \
    _cmd(mknodat,259) \
    _cmd(fchownat,260) \
    _cmd(futimesat,261) \
    _cmd(newfstatat,262) \
    _cmd(unlinkat,263) \
    _cmd(renameat,264) \
    _cmd(linkat,265) \
    _cmd(symlinkat,266) \
    _cmd(readlinkat,267) \
    _cmd(fchmodat,268) \
    _cmd(faccessat,269) \
    _cmd(pselect6,270) \
    _cmd(ppoll,271) \
    _cmd(unshare,272) \
    _cmd(set_robust_list,273) \
    _cmd(get_robust_list,274) \
    _cmd(splice,275) \
    _cmd(tee,276) \
    _cmd(sync_file_range,277) \
    _cmd(vmsplice,278) \
    _cmd(move_pages,279) \
    _cmd(utimensat,280) \
    _cmd(epoll_pwait,281) \
    _cmd(signalfd,282) \
    _cmd(timerfd_create,283) \
    _cmd(eventfd,284) \
    _cmd(fallocate,285) \
    _cmd(timerfd_settime,286) \
    _cmd(timerfd_gettime,287) \
    _cmd(accept4,288) \
    _cmd(signalfd4,289) \
    _cmd(eventfd2,290) \
    _cmd(epoll_create1,291) \
    _cmd(dup3,292) \
    _cmd(pipe2,293) \
    _cmd(inotify_init1,294) \
    _cmd(preadv,295) \
    _cmd(pwritev,296) \
    _cmd(rt_tgsigqueueinfo,297) \
    _cmd(perf_event_open,298) \
    _cmd(recvmmsg,299) \
    _cmd(fanotify_init,300) \
    _cmd(fanotify_mark,301) \
    _cmd(prlimit64,302) \
    _cmd(name_to_handle_at,303) \
    _cmd(open_by_handle_at,304) \
    _cmd(clock_adjtime,305) \
    _cmd(syncfs,306) \
    _cmd(sendmmsg,307) \
    _cmd(setns,308) \
    _cmd(getcpu,309) \
    _cmd(process_vm_readv,310) \
    _cmd(process_vm_writev,311) \
    _cmd(kcmp,312) \
    _cmd(finit_module,313) \
    _cmd(sched_setattr,314) \
    _cmd(sched_getattr,315) \
    _cmd(renameat2,316) \
    _cmd(seccomp,317) \
    _cmd(getrandom,318) \
    _cmd(memfd_create,319) \
    _cmd(kexec_file_load,320) \
    _cmd(bpf,321) \
    _cmd(execveat,322) \
    _cmd(userfaultfd,323) \
    _cmd(membarrier,324) \
    _cmd(mlock2,325) \
    _cmd(copy_file_range,326) \
    _cmd(preadv2,327) \
    _cmd(pwritev2,328) \
    _cmd(pkey_mprotect,329) \
    _cmd(pkey_alloc,330) \
    _cmd(pkey_free,331) \
    _cmd(statx,332) \
    _cmd(io_pgetevents,333) \
    _cmd(rseq,334) \
    _cmd(pidfd_send_signal,424) \
    _cmd(io_uring_setup,425) \
    _cmd(io_uring_enter,426) \
    _cmd(io_uring_register,427) \
    _cmd(open_tree,428) \
    _cmd(move_mount,429) \
    _cmd(fsopen,430) \
    _cmd(fsconfig,431) \
    _cmd(fsmount,432) \
    _cmd(fspick,433) \
    _cmd(pidfd_open,434) \
    _cmd(clone3,435)

#define SVCDEF(_sym,_val) \
    [__NR_ ## _sym] = #_sym,

const char *svcdef[500] = {
    NRALL(SVCDEF)
};

const char *
svcname(int svcno)
{

    return svcdef[svcno];
}
```

---

Here is the target/test program (`target.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAXTHREADS          5

void *
func(void *ptr)
{

    sleep(2);

    return (void *) 0;
}

int
main(void)
{

    pthread_t tid[MAXTHREADS];

    int err;
    int count = 0;

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < MAXTHREADS;  ++idx, ++count) {
        err = pthread_create(&tid[idx],NULL,func,NULL);
        if (err != 0) {
            printf("main: idx=%d -- %s\n",idx,strerror(err));
            break;
        }
        printf("main: start idx=%d\n",idx);
    }

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx) {
        pthread_join(tid[idx],NULL);
        printf("main: joined idx=%d\n",idx);
    }

    printf("main: done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Compile with:

```
cc -o trace trace.c
cc -o target target.c -lpthread
```

---

Here is the normal output (`./target`):

```
main: start idx=0
main: start idx=1
main: start idx=2
main: start idx=3
main: start idx=4
main: joined idx=0
main: joined idx=1
main: joined idx=2
main: joined idx=3
main: joined idx=4
main: done
```

---

Here is the output for `./trace -L2 ./target`. Note that the trace program puts debug/trace output in the file `./LOG`:

```
main: start idx=0
main: start idx=1
main: idx=2 -- Bad file descriptor
main: joined idx=0
main: joined idx=1
main: done
```