# Use LD_PRELOAD to intercept system calls from library which is statically linked?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linker, glibc, ld-preload

I have an application statically linked with a third party library. The third party library makes system calls (presumably via glibc).

I would like to intercept these system calls by writing a "wrapper" library and loading it first via LD_PRELOAD. However, I have read LD_PRELOAD does not work with static-linking.

Does this linkage requirement only apply to the "wrapper" library? It's okay to still have the third party library statically-linked with my application?

Comment: You probably can _not_ do this with `LD_PRELOAD` with static linking of `glibc`. Even if you can, finding _all_ the syscall wrappers to trap (e.g. `open`, `open64`, `fopen`, `fopen64`, etc. with/without symbol versioning) can be sporadic. You can do this by running the target program under a custom launcher program [that you write] that uses `ptrace` to intercept syscalls. For an example of this, see my answer: [Forcing `pthread_create` to fail for test purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77247274/5382650)

Comment: @CraigEstey I don't think I am statically-linking glibc. I am just explicitly statically linking the third party library from cmake. I think people have to really go out of their way to statically-link glibc?

Comment: "*I think people have to really go out of their way to statically-link glibc?*" -- Not really. It's as simple as specifying the `-static` option in the build command (and of course having a static version of the library available). How you checked your executable to see which routines in dynamic libraries it does depend on?

Comment: Recently, I tried to help someone with exactly the same issue as yours: [Override open function using LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77490351/5382650) I did a lot of hacking to find the symbols to intercept, but it became tedious. Again, I recommend the `ptrace` approach because it will catch syscalls and be guaranteed to work, regardless of the target program linking. YMMV

Comment: Is it XY question - do you want to intercept system calls _or_ do you specifically only ask about using only specifically LD_PRELOAD to intercept system calls? Why not use strace? `I am just explicitly statically linking the third party` Is the library itself fully statically linked and makes no external calls _or you_ are linking it statically in your build system?

Comment: @sawdust Statically linking `glibc` seems misguided.  See [**Why is statically linking glibc discouraged?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476533/why-is-statically-linking-glibc-discouraged).  TLDR:  "But if the main program is statically linked with the C library, `dlopen` has to go load a *second* copy of the C library to satisfy the modules' load requirements."  `glibc` loads its shared object *anyway*.  The static link was a waste of time.

Comment: @sawdust If I run `ldd my_exe` I get `libstdc++.so.6` and `libc.so.6` so I presume I am indeed dynamically linking?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm not monitoring these library/system calls, I would like to replace their behavior. Given my previous comment, i think, suggests I am dynamically linking glibc, I can use LD_PRELOAD with a wrapper library to intercept?

Comment: @rare77 -- Seems that way. One way to see the entry points that need resolving is with `strings`. See https://superuser.com/questions/1176200/no-such-file-when-it-exists `ldd` is typically not available on embedded systems, so I resort to using `strings`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle -- Sometimes the needed dynamic libraries are not on the target system, so a statically-linked executable that has no external dependencies is more portable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084611/what-does-sh-executable-pathnot-found-mean/21131076#21131076

Comment: @sawdust If a developer delivers software without at least documenting *all* dependencies, that developer is IMO incompetent.  Note that Linux along with just about every other OS provides package management systems that allow delivery of software with required dependencies.  And **no**, it's not "more portable".  Statically-linked software is bound and dependent on **one** and only one kernel system call interface, which is *not* a documented, stable API like those provided by the C and POSIX standards.

Comment: (cont)  And nevermind that statically-linking `glibc` is *still* misguided.  Follow my previous link - `glibc` will dynamically-load it's shared object copy anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Use LD_PRELOAD to intercept system calls

It is not possible to use `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept system calls. With `LD_PRELOAD` you may override symbol resolved from an external library, for example a function. That's very separate and unrelated to system call.

If the code makes a system call without ever calling an external symbol, it's impossible to intercept it with `LD_PRELOAD`.

It is possible to override function resulting in system calls with `LD_PRELOAD`, however there is no clear relationship between them. For example, `open()` C function may result in `open` or `openat` system call, it can only be known in advance by analyzing the source code. Or, I think like `pthread_create` will result in several of system calls. Because there is no clear relationship and functions are unrelated to system calls, bottom line it is not possible to intercept system calls with `LD_PRELOAD`

Comment: *It is not possible to use `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept system calls.*  I'm not totally convinced the OP hasn't gotten confused by the labeling of **library functions** such as `open()` as "system calls".  Thank the misguided people who say things like "`fopen()` is a function, but `open()` is a system call."  But they are both **functions** in reality.

Comment: That's why I think `open()` which can use `open` or `openat` is a good example. I remember actually reading some articles about https://lwn.net/Articles/738695/ about this issue and seccomp.

Comment: That's also *another* reason why statically linking system libraries is a **really** bad idea in the first place - the internal implementation can change.  Nevermind how `glibc` in particular needs to be able to load it's shared object anyway...

Comment: Hi, by "system calls" I did mean the library functions defined within glibc. So would I still be able to do this if my application is statically linked to a third party, but dynamically linked to the wrapper library?